# nonfrenchspacing error missing package?

Tags: microtype

My tex file works fine as long as I don't put my bibliography inside, in which case I get the error

```
(microtype) \nonfrenchspacing is active. Adjustment of
(microtype) interword spacing will disable it. You might want
(microtype) to add \microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
(microtype) to your preamble.
```

Am I missing some package?

Comment: are you sure your files are in latin9 (most editors will use UTF-8 these days)

Comment: you have completely changed the question since my first comment!  have you tried adding the line that the warning suggests that you add?

Comment: I think it was chanced by someone else. Basically I had the following error before I got rid of an accent \' ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `latin9'.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...ons in Information \& Systems}, 6: 221��

Comment: and after I removed the \' I got the error that you see above

Comment: that's a warning not an error I think and also it suggests the necessary correction.